# PHP ksort() function is not sorting at all on remote server. Throws no error either

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, nginx, ksort

I'm writing a PHP function that takes an array of $_GET parameters and spits out an SHA signature of these (salted with a secret) to verify authenticity.

Currently it looks like this:

```
private function generateShasign($fields) {
    unset($fields['SHASIGN']);
    ksort($fields, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
    $phrase = "";
    foreach($fields as $key => $field){
        // if(!empty($field) && $field != '0'){
            $phrase .= strtoupper($key) . '=' . $field . 'SECRETSALT';
        // }
    }
    return strtoupper(sha1($phrase));
}
```

It unsets the SHA-SIGNATURE parameter from the request, puts them in 'KEY=value.SECRETSALT" format and sorts them (using ksort())

Now, this works PERFECTLY on my local environment. The returned SHA equals the SHA var in the get request and everything goes fine.

On a remote testing server however, it does not work. Ksort does not seem to be sorting at all. AND it does not throw an error.

A quick print_r($phrase) returns (on the faulty remote server):

```
SHA SIGN: ORDERID=ge9xBpZjXSECRETSALTCURRENCY=EURSECRETSALTAMOUNT=50SECRETSALTPM=CreditCardSECRETSALTACCEPTANCE=test123SECRETSALTSTATUS=5SECRETSALTCARDNO=XXXXXXXXXXXX1111SECRETSALTED=0214SECRETSALTCN=MATTHIASSECRETSALTTRXDATE=02/22/14SECRETSALTPAYID=28345877SECRETSALTNCERROR=0SECRETSALTBRAND=VISASECRETSALTIP=84.198.21.23SECRETSALT7F0B539A1DECC55E57860DEB9F7B3A301E1960AD
```

and on the proper working environment:

```
ACCEPTANCE=test123SECRETSALTAMOUNT=50SECRETSALTBRAND=VISASECRETSALTCARDNO=XXXXXXXXXXXX1111SECRETSALTCN=MATTHIASSECRETSALTCURRENCY=EURSECRETSALTED=0214SECRETSALTIP=84.198.21.23SECRETSALTNCERROR=0SECRETSALTORDERID=iXAVBM1SBSECRETSALTPAYID=28345882SECRETSALTPM=CreditCardSECRETSALTSTATUS=5SECRETSALTTRXDATE=02/22/14SECRETSALT
```

Obviously, ksort() is not sorting anything on the remote environment. Hence why the order of the parameters in the to-be-sha-encoded phrase is exactly the same as the order in the GET request.

Why ksort() is not functioning AND not throwing an error is puzzling me bigtime.

Locally i'm running PHP/5.4.22 (Apache). And remotely i -believe- PHP 5.3 (NGINX)

UPDATE:

ksort returns false. Can not figure out why it's failing though.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you certain error reporting is turned on the remote server?  Test by adding `ini_set('display_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: That's not ksort's problem. Your "faulty" server is feeding in different data. You need to do a `var_dump($fields)` and then track where that data is coming from.

Comment: A little offtopic, but you should consider using the same version of software as you use in your production environment. If your live server uses PHP 5.3 you should develop with PHP 5.3. That avoids a lot of problems. Best way to do it is by using [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/). You can use [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/) to generate a configuration.

Comment: @cale_b: Yes, i'm completely sure error reporting is turned on. Other errors do generate a PHP notice, but this one isn't. Not even after applying those lines

Comment: @Marc B: Tried and tested. the $fields variable is completely identical in both environments. the output of ksort() isn't. The fact that no warning /notice is given makes me think i'm missing something obvious though...

Comment: @ragol: True. Very true. This hasn't been the first php versioning related issue i've had on this project. Will heed your advice carefully from now on : ) Vagrant looks promising, thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go:

http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0

> `Added support for SORT_NATURAL and SORT_FLAG_CASE in array sort functions (sort, rsort, ksort, krsort, asort, arsort and array_multisort).`

Comment: Huh, i actually read those lines in the documentation a few times ... Was confused by the "(PHP 4, PHP 5)" flag under the Ksort() header. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The SORT_NATURAL and  SORT_FLAG_CASE were not working on the remote environment. For watherver reason, i don't know. SORT_STRING however *was* working. So i worked around my issue by converting the keys to uppercase first, and then sorting with SORT_STRING.

Doesn't solve the issue, but it's a viable workaround i guess.